# How to manipulate data in dplyr across 2 different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, dplyr, conditional-statements

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(reporter, year) %>% 
  summarize(TI = sum(trade_value_usd[df1 != "World"], na.rm = T) / sum(trade_value_usd[df1$partner == "World"], na.rm = T) / 
              (sum(df2$trade_value_usd) / sum(df3$trade_value_usd)))
```

I need df2 to follow same df1 criteria in such operations, how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact task, you could define a function and use `df1` and `df2` as arguments:

```r
manipulator <- function(data) {
  output <- data %>%
              group_by(reporter, year) %>% 
              summarize(TI = sum(trade_value_usd[data != "World"], na.rm = T) / sum(trade_value_usd[data$partner == "World"], na.rm = T) / 
                (sum(df2$trade_value_usd) / sum(df3$trade_value_usd))) 
  return(output) # or print or something else 
}

manipulator(df1)
manipulator(df2)
```